# How to setup facebook-connect for authlogic in rails3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, authlogic

I have been searching a lot on the net to get facebook-connect integrated with authlogic in rails3. There are a number of solutions based on facebooker, oauth etc. but none of them seem to say anything on whether they work with rails 3 or not. Can anyone guide to me on how to get facebook-connect working with authlogic in "rails3". I see that there are a lot of questions related to this on the site but none seems to have actually answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use http://www.janrain.com/products/engage with this gem https://github.com/tardate/authlogic_rpx. This combo works amazing with two of my projects and it is free if you only want to use authentication (like in my case).

PS. look at railscast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/233-engage-with-devise. I know that, this podcast show how to use Janrain with Devise, but it helped me with Authlogic so it also can help you.